Cubejs pre_aggregations not working for BigQuery tables
In a cubejs setup with CUBEJS_DEV_MODE ON, facing issue setting up pre_aggregations on BigQuery cubes:
pre_aggregation has a refresh_key set for every day refresh as :
refresh_key:
    sql: "SELECT FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%d', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) as refresh_key" 
scheduled_refresh: false

but the query errors out with error:
Error while querying: scheduler-f2726d86-5154-47cb-ba50-444a73af13e5 (209189ms)
{
 "queueId": 84,
 "queueSize": 0,
 "queryKey": [
  "SELECT FLOOR((UNIX_TIMESTAMP()) / 120) as refresh_key",
  []
 ],
 "queuePrefix": "SQL_QUERY_EXT_STANDALONE",
 "timeInQueue": 0
} 
AggregateError: 
  at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1118:18)
  at afterConnectMultiple (node:net:1685:7)

Doubts:

Why does it fallback to default refresh time of 2 mins for BigQuery and with a inconsistent time function UNIX_TIMESTAMP() when we are explicitly setting sql for refresh time?
Does it have something to do with Development mode, documentation says dev mode only impacts aggregations for which scheduled_refresh is true?
Is there an issue with db concurrency and connections?

Appreciate your help!
